# Intellij IDEA not display Django in the facet list

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea

I am using Fedora 20 with OpenJDK-1.7.0.60 setup. I can setup and run Intellij IDEA 13.1 successfully, then setup Python plugin. Well, when I tried generate a project from Intellij with Python module selectly, I could not find Django facet in the technology part. I searched web but could not find any solution, even any question. I stuck and cannot do anything. Please help.

Note: Python and related Django had been installed on my machine before I setup the plugin.

Regards.

Comment: @MrMojoRisin Please stop. You're not contributing anything to questions by making pointless edits. Highlighting software/framework/library names is *not* helping anything.

Comment: check if you got any django console in `setting>console` , and have you configured project sdk? and please check if you can use django-admin

Comment: @ruddra When I went to "Template Project Settings" -> "Console", I saw only "Python Console". I couldn't know configuring project SDK (I can't generate a project.). I can using django-admin by "django-admin" command on the console.

Comment: well if u dnt mind, can u do a simple test? create  a django project by django-admin console, then import that project in intellijidea. check if it imports django modules.

Comment: @ruddra Thanks. I can do it, Django support had been enabled in Intellij from the beginning, so I can generate run configurations for both server and test, start Django console and so on, but I feel still something missing. I think I can use Intellij with Django as it is currently, but I will be waiting for the solution for this incomprehensible problem.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Your symptoms are similar to a problem I've also had, which was solved by editing the IDEA module file, which will appear as `{your_project_name}.iml`.  This file is either in the root of your project (or module) or in the `.idea` directory of the project.

You'll likely see that the module element's type attribute is `JAVA_MODULE`.   Change this to `PYTHON_MODULE`, save the file, and restart Intellij.

You'll likely see this:

```
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
```

Or this:

```
<module version="4">
```

In either case, what you want is for the `type` attribute to say `PYTHON_MODULE`:

```
<module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
```

After saving that, when you go into Project Structure and add a Facet, you'll see Django.

My guess is when your project was initially opened in Intellij, the IDE did not recognize the directory as a python module, and set it to the default (Java).

Comment: Thank you! After changing the module you have to disable python facets in File > Project Structure > Facets

Comment: Just changing `JAVA_MODULE` to `PYTHON_MODULE` didn't resolve the warning. I ended up just removing the whole .idea directory and restarting. Frustrating....

Comment: For others, I already had python set as my project sdk, but I still had to edit this from JAVA_MODULE to PYTHON_MODULE and reopen the project. The django facet then appeared. More completion works now!

Comment: what a hassle...