# Enable Django support in IntelliJ?

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, configuration, buildout

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24438244/595305), but it doesn't help.

I just made a new project in IntelliJ, (Community 2020.1 EAP). This is a Linux OS (Mint 18.3).

In the left-hand panel I chose "Python".

When I have created it I go File --> Project structure.
I click "Facets" in the left-hand panel. In the middle panel it says "No facets are configured" and under that "Detection".

I click the "+" sign and then where it says "Buildout Support facet will be added to the selected module" I click OK.

After that, in the middle panel, Buildout Support is highlighted, and in the right-hand part it says "Use paths from script:" (with a blank text field) and under the field "Set to `<buildout-dir>/bin/django.py` for proper Django support".

This leaves me very puzzled. It suggests that there is a setting "buildout-dir", and even supposing I can find a file "django.py" in a directory "bin" I haven't got a clue what I'm meant to enter in that box: the full path to "django.py"? The full path above "bin"?

Then I go looking on my machine for django.py:

```
369] mike@M17A ~/IdeaProjects/TempDjango $  locate django.py
/home/mike/.local/share/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.1/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/teamcity/django.py
/home/mike/python_venvs/test_venv369/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py
```

Neither looks at all promising. Naturally I have tried "using these paths from script"... but as neither is a ".../bin/django.py" path I'm not surprised absolutely nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me what I should do? Can anyone explain what "buildout", "buildout support" and/or "buildout-dir" are meant to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Django support for IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition Python plug-in. This feature is available only for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and PyCharm Professional edition.

Comment: Thanks. Fortunately it doesn't stop me actually building a Django project of course. Mightn't it be an idea to remove any mention of configuring Django support in the Community Edition, if this is not too much trouble?

Comment: Sure, I've submitted a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42356. Sorry for the inconvenience.